# Share one y axis for four different boxplots

Tags: r, boxplot

I work with the iris dataset, the aim is to get 4 boxplots next to each other and make them all share an y-axis that goes from 0 to 8

```
par(mfrow=c(1,4))
boxplot(iris$Sepal.Length, width = 3)
boxplot(iris$Sepal.Width, width = 3)
boxplot(iris$Petal.Length, width = 3)
boxplot(iris$Petal.Width, width = 3)
```

I have the 4 plots next to each other now but they all have their own y-axis, suited to their own min and max.

How can i make them share a y-axis?
I also want to have a x-axis where I can label them with "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width" and so on.

Solutions without the ggplot if possible, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three options:

### base graphics

Determine the y range before plotting. For this there are two options, choose from one of the `ylim=` below:

```r
### if you have no outliers or will not plot them
ylim <- range(boxplot.stats(as.matrix(iris[,-5]))$stats)

### if you have outliers and/or want to leave room for them, then
ylim <- range(as.matrix(iris[,-5]))
```

In this case, the overall range does not change, though `Sepal.Width` *does* contain some outliers in the plot.

From here, plot them with `ylim=ylim`:

```r
par(mfrow = c(1, 4))
boxplot(iris$Sepal.Length, width = 3, ylim = ylim)
boxplot(iris$Sepal.Width, width = 3, ylim = ylim)
boxplot(iris$Petal.Length, width = 3, ylim = ylim)
boxplot(iris$Petal.Width, width = 3, ylim = ylim)
```

[image: base graphics, four boxplots]

### base graphics, take 2

Group them, after reshaping.

```r
irislong <- reshape2::melt(iris, "Species", variable.name = "Var")
head(irislong)
#   Species          Var value
# 1  setosa Sepal.Length   5.1
# 2  setosa Sepal.Length   4.9
# 3  setosa Sepal.Length   4.7
# 4  setosa Sepal.Length   4.6
# 5  setosa Sepal.Length   5.0
# 6  setosa Sepal.Length   5.4
boxplot(value ~ Var, data = irislong)
```

[image: base graphics, reshaped data]

(One case also use `tidyr::pivot_longer` for reshaping it, which I demonstrate in the ggplot2 section, below.)

#### ggplot2

(Provided even though you asked for non-ggplot2, because it provides a little more power at times, and some think that it looks better, subjective of course.)

```r
ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(iris, -Species), aes(value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(name ~ .)
```

[image: ggplot2 boxplots]

If you prefer it in the same direction as the base plots, then

```r
ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(iris, -Species), aes(value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(. ~ name) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: ggplot2, rotated]

---

In general, using the formula method (in the second base graphics plot) or the faceting (within ggplot2) allows you to group boxplots by more than just one variable.

Comment: Thx, one question, what is the -5 at the beginning for? (when you determine the range)

Comment: In order to determine the true range of numbers, we need to ignore the non-numerical columns. In this case, the 5th column is `Species`. With different data, instead of being *exclusive* (removing the 5th column), you might need or prefer to be *inclusive* in your numerical columns with something like `range(boxplot.stats(as.matrix(iris[,1:4]))$stats)`

Comment: Ah makes sense. One issue: it says "there is no package named reshape2"

Comment: Okay, two options to reshape the data: (1) install it, or (2) use `tidyr` (in the ggplot2 portion). If neither of those are installed, reshaping data in R gets a bit more difficult ... I've never really mastered `stats::reshape`, but you can try to learn that.

Comment: installed the reshape package, that works now. Next problem: in the last command line it says "can't find object 'Var'"

Comment: I used `reshape2`, not `reshape`, they are different.